# amp-animation onload runs keyframes

Tags: html, css, amp-html, amp-animation

I am trying to display a header only when the user scrolls up, for that, I managed to get it to work after the user has started scrolling.

However, the header is displayed on the load time event because of amp's `on="enter..."` action. I tried to find a way to hide it based on the position of another element but I can't get it to work with the functions available on amp which seem to only be something like `height, width` etc... Which is not what I want.

- I wanted to display the `header` based on the Y position of `.spacer` element.

This is what I have been able to come up with so far:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.ampstart.com/templates/article.amp">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async="" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-animation" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-animation-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-position-observer" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-position-observer-0.1.js" async></script>

  <style amp-custom>
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    main {

      padding: 10px;
      max-width: 412px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: #fff;
      top: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
      position: relative;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      text-indent: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .spacer {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEE 50%, white 50%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(#EEE 50%, white 50%);
      background-size: 100% 3em;
      transform: translateY(-60px);
    }

    #marker {
      position: relative;
      /*top: 50px;*/
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <h1>Show Header</h1>
</header>
<amp-animation id="hideAnim" layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "easing": "ease-out",
      "duration": "500ms",
      "fill": "both",
      "iterations": "1",
      "direction": "alternate",
      "animations": [{
        "selector": "header",
        "keyframes": [{
          "transform": "translateY(-60px)"
        },
          {
            "transform": "translateY(0)"
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>

<amp-animation id="scrollToAnim"
               layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "easing": "ease-in",
      "duration": "0",
      "fill": "both",
      "iterations": "1",
      "direction": "alternate",
      "animations": [{
        "selector": ".spacer",
        "keyframes": [{
          "transform": "translateY(-60px)"
        },
          {
            "transform": "translateY(0)"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>

<main>
  <!-- Invisible 0x0px marker div that sits 100px off the top -->
  <div id="marker">
    <amp-position-observer on="enter:hideAnim.start; exit:hideAnim.start, hideAnim.reverse, scrollToAnim.start;" layout="nodisplay">
    </amp-position-observer>
  </div>
  <div id="default" class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</main>
</body>

</html>
```

I do not want to see header after the `onload` event. Currently it shows the following after page load:

[image]

As you can see, the header is overlayed in the back.

- I don't want to see the header on load time.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.